# react-native-geolocation-service working perfectly fine in debug mode as expected but not working in release mode

Tags: android, react-native, geolocation

I am using react-native-geolocation-service package for getting location. Package working perfectly fine in debug mode but in release apk its load and give error Permission denied.

***Tried solutions:***
remove node module and install again
gradlew clean
chche clean
but nothing work

```
import {
  Alert,
  Linking,
  PermissionsAndroid,
  Platform,
  ToastAndroid,
  DeviceEventEmitter,
} from "react-native";
import Geolocation from "react-native-geolocation-service";
import LocationServicesDialogBox from "react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box";

class locationClass {
  hasPermissionIOS = async () => {
    const openSetting = () => {
      Linking.openSettings().catch(() => {
        Alert.alert("Unable to open settings");
      });
    };
    const status = await Geolocation.requestAuthorization("whenInUse");

    if (status === "granted") {
      return true;
    }

    if (status === "denied") {
      Alert.alert("Location permission denied");
    }

    if (status === "disabled") {
      Alert.alert(
        `Turn on Location Services to allow "${appConfig.displayName}" to determine your location.`,
        "",
        [
          { text: "Go to Settings", onPress: openSetting },
          { text: "Don't Use Location", onPress: () => {} },
        ]
      );
    }

    return false;
  };

  hasLocationPermission = async () => {
    if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
      const hasPermission = await hasPermissionIOS();
      alert("has ios", hasPermission);
      return hasPermission;
    }

    // if (Platform.OS === "android") {
    //   return true;
    // }

    const hasPermission = await PermissionsAndroid.check(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    );
    console.log("has android", hasPermission);

    // if (hasPermission) {
    //   return true;
    // }

    const status = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    );

    if (status === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      //   ToastAndroid.show(
      //     "Location permission granted by user.",
      //     ToastAndroid.LONG
      //   );
      return true;
    }

    if (status === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.DENIED) {
      ToastAndroid.show(
        "Location permission denied by user.",
        ToastAndroid.LONG
      );
    } else if (status === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.NEVER_ASK_AGAIN) {
      ToastAndroid.show(
        "Location permission revoked by user.",
        ToastAndroid.LONG
      );
    }

    return false;
  };

  getLocation = async (callback) => {
    const hasPermission = await this.hasLocationPermission();
    console.log("hasPermission", hasPermission);
    if (!hasPermission) {
    }
    await this.checkiflocationisEnable();
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        console.log(position);
        callback({ isSuccess: true, position });
      },
      (error) => {
        //Alert.alert(`Code ${error.code}`, error.message);
        console.log(error);
        callback({ isSuccess: false, error });
      },
      {
        accuracy: {
          android: "high",
          ios: "best",
        },
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 15000,
        maximumAge: 3600000,
        distanceFilter: 0,
        forceRequestLocation: true,
        forceLocationManager: true,
        showLocationDialog: true,
      }
    );
  };
  checkiflocationisEnable = () => {
    if (Platform.OS === "android")
      LocationServicesDialogBox.checkLocationServicesIsEnabled({
        message:
          "<h2></h2> \
           wants to access your location to show you available nearby.<br/><br/>\
                              <br/><br/>",
        ok: "YES",
        cancel: "NO",
      })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log("response", response);

          //locationTracking(dispatch, getState, geolocationSettings);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("error", error.message);
        });
    DeviceEventEmitter.addListener(
      "locationProviderStatusChange",
      function (status) {
        // only trigger when "providerListener" is enabled
        console.log("status", status); //  status => {enabled: false, status: "disabled"} or {enabled: true, status: "enabled"}
      }
    );
  };
}
const locationServices = new locationClass();
export { locationServices };
```

package version

```
"react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.0-beta.2",
"react-native": "0.64.2",
```

app/build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation. If none specified and
 *   // "index.android.js" exists, it will be used. Otherwise "index.js" is
 *   // default. Can be overridden with ENTRY_FILE environment variable.
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // https://reactnative.dev/docs/performance#enable-the-ram-format
 *   bundleCommand: "ram-bundle",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
        enableHermes: false
]

apply from: '../../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/gradle.groovy'
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/expo-updates/scripts/create-manifest-android.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {

    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
        useNewCruncher = false
    }
    signingConfigs {
            release {
            storeFile file('./dbazzar_app.keystore')
            storePassword 'h2b2912'
            keyAlias 'com_dbazzar_app'
            keyPassword 'h2b2912'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.dbazzar.apptwo'
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 34
        versionName "2.5.2"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable false
           // useProguard true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation files('/Users/apple/Desktop/ReactNative/dbz2userapp/android/app/libs/paylibrary-release.aar')
    def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.0.0'

implementation project(':react-native-background-timer')
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group: 'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group: 'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', module: 'okhttp'
    }
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group: 'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    addUnimodulesDependencies()

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '6.8.3'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following attribute:

`forceLocationManager: false`

Answer (score 0):

Add this
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />` to your AndroidManifest.xml